Is there a Javascript function in canvas which can randomly position a square such that a specific point (x,y) will be inside it?
This is for a game. I am using canvas to draw a square, and I want the square to be positioned randomly on the canvas, but still contain the point (x,y) where the player starts. I am having trouble coding this by hand.

No there is not a function to do that. You'll need to create one yourself. Create a random number between -box size and +box height and again for width, then you can use it as an offset on the player x,y

What exactly does "positioned randomly" mean to you? What distribution of positions do you expect? Is the size of the square given, and if not, should its random generation correspond to the position somehow or be otherwise constrained?

Using a function to randomize number between a range, like my random_int. Then we need to put the top left corner of the square between playerX - squareSize and playerX and same for Y.


function random_int(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function drawPlayer(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "green"
  ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawSquare(ctx, x, y, size) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, size, size);
}

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

  var cx = canvas.width
  var cy = canvas.height
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cx, cy)
  var edge = Math.min(cx, cy)
  var px = random_int(0, cx)
  var py = random_int(0, cy)
  var size = random_int(20, edge)
  var x1 = px - size
  var x2 = px
  var xc = random_int(Math.max(px - size, 0), Math.min(px, cx - size))
  var y1 = py - size
  var y2 = py
  var yc = random_int(Math.max(py - size, 0), Math.min(py, cy - size))

  drawPlayer(ctx, px, py)
  drawSquare(ctx, xc, yc, size)

}

draw()
body {
  background: #333;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
<button onclick="draw()">again</button>



